# Remove all the occurrences of &nbsp; and , using javascript from an input field

Tags: javascript

I have an input field of type text with the following description

```
<input type="text" id="inputID"/>
```

It has the following content

```
hello &nbsp; and , world &nbsp; and , world hello and world &nbsp; and ,
```

With the content on the above input field, I am trying to remove all the occurrences of   and , using javascript.

Presently, I am doing this but don't know how to pass it to the input field using the element id="inputID" of the input tag

```
var message= content.replace(/[&]nbsp[;][,]/gi," ");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex must be `/&nbsp;|,/g` ie any `&nbsp;` or `,` in the string. `g` stand for global search.

```js
var inputValue = document.getElementById("inputID").value ;

var cleanedValue= inputValue.replace(/&nbsp;|,/g," ");

document.getElementById("inputID").value = cleanedValue;
```

```html
<input type="text" id="inputID" value="hello &nbsp; and , world &nbsp; and , world hello and world &nbsp; and ,"/>
```

---

Or if you find one liner code more fancy then do this.

```
document.getElementById("inputID").value = document.getElementById("inputID").value.replace(/&nbsp;|,/g," ");;
```

Comment: How do I pass it to the input id of the element.